# Strange process behaviour on virtualized Ubuntu

Tags: process

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Windows 8.1 using VirtualBox. I'm approaching to Operating systems and the following program shows a strange result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
printf("I'm the parent, my PID is %d, my parent is process %d\n",
getpid(), getppid());
fork();
printf("This sentence has been printed by process: %d my parent is process %d\n",
getpid(), getppid());
return 0;
}
```

I compile it with GCC and run it. Then the output is the following:

```
kocks@kocks-VirtualBox:~$ ./uno
I'm the parent, my PID is 3746, my parent is process 3507
This sentence has been printed by process: 3746 my parent is process 3507
kocks@kocks-VirtualBox:~$ This sentence has been printed by process: 3747 my parent is process 2857
```

The problem is with the third sentence: I expect "my parent process is 3746"! In particular, The number (2857) is always the same and changes only after  rebooting the VM.  There are some points to be added:

1. If I add a `wait()` just before the return, it perfectly works
2. When I try to "pimp" the VM (like giving it two processors, more RAM etc.) it sometimes and randomly returns the correct output

So I think the problem is in the VM, am I right? How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**
When running the program from Ubuntu in dual boot, this is the output:

```
I'm the parent, my PID is 3186, my parent is process 2454 
This sentence has been printed by process: 3186 my parent is process 2454
This sentence has been printed by process: 3187 my parent is process 3186
```

How is it possible?

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265718/fork-child-and-parent-processes

Answer (score 2):

I tested this on 2 virtualbox setup, both using OS X as host, and assigned only 1 CPU for each client.

**1 Ubuntu 14.04.2**

In this setup, under X window environment, the behavior matched OP

```
john@U64D:~$ ./a
I'm the parent, my PID is 2682, my parent is process 2632
This sentence has been printed by process: 2682 my parent is process 2632
john@U64D:~$ This sentence has been printed by process: 2683 my parent is process 1673
```

The parent process 1673 will remain the same until I logout and login again

```
john@U64D:~$ ./a
I'm the parent, my PID is 3787, my parent is process 3740
This sentence has been printed by process: 3787 my parent is process 3740
john@U64D:~$ This sentence has been printed by process: 3788 my parent is process 3107
./a
I'm the parent, my PID is 3790, my parent is process 3740
This sentence has been printed by process: 3790 my parent is process 3740
john@U64D:~$ This sentence has been printed by process: 3791 my parent is process 3107
```

3107 is **init --user**

```
john@U64D:~$ ps -ef|grep 3107
john      3107  2911  0 15:07 ?        00:00:00 init --user
```

However, result will match Barmar answer under non-X environment (eg. tty1).

**2 Debian 7.8**

This setup matched Barmar answer, for both X and non-X environment.

john@debian:~$ ./a

```
I'm the parent, my PID is 3455, my parent is process 3406
This sentence has been printed by process: 3455 my parent is process 3406
john@debian:~$ This sentence has been printed by process: 3456 my parent is process 1
```

**Conclusion**

OP observation is result of Ubuntu using session init for the default X environment. Detail information for session init can be found [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-init).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `wait()`, the parent can finish before the child ever gets a chance to run. By the time the child process calls `getppid()`, the parent has exited, so the child is adopted by `init`. On a normal Unix implementation, the PID of `init` is 1, so you would expect it to say *my parent is process 1* when this happens. But apparently VirtualBox changes this.

If you use `wait()`, this makes the parent wait for the child to finish before it exits. So the child will never become an orphan.

Comment: I am guessing if the the program is start within a terminal windows, 2857 is the terminal PID.

Comment: You mean the grandparent process? That's not how orphan process adoption works, it always goes to `init`.

Comment: You also said that the PPID only changes when you reboot the VM. If it were the terminal process, it would change if you ran your program in a different terminal window.

Comment: This sounds like the prctl subreaper feature. Upstart uses this to give each session its own init process.

Comment: Indeed it does. http://linux.die.net/man/2/prctl